# Conditional formatting to have transparent font colour

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I'm not sure if this is possible - I would like to have a conditional type formating on a field in a continous form, which will give the font colour of the field a transparent colour, so that the result is hidden.

I would like to do this to hide out a bunch of zero values. So far, I've tried setting the font colour to white on a zero value, but my odd lines have a light grey background, so it's still showing there. Is it possible to have a transparent font color, or to match it to the background colour of the line it's on?

Comment: Which version of Access are you using? You've tagged both 2010 and 2013; you should only tag the version you're actually using, as the answer may differ.

Comment: Ok good point..  I use Access 2013 and MSaccess 2010 at work..  Probably it is for this when i transfer databases that i often have issues at work which i dont have at home..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's invalid for you to have 0s in the your results, don't refomat the colour to hide them, rewrite the query to exclude them / replace them with a blank or null value. If 0 is a valid result, then you shouldn't hide it, even if it looks ugly.

Comment: +1.  I disagree that "if 0 is a valid result, you shouldn't hide it, even if it looks ugly".  That depends on the functional need.  If the purpose of the form is to draw the attention of the user to other values, suppressing the 0 may be best.